# Remove sprites Libgdx Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

So I have a sprite that intersects another sprite, and when that happens i want to remove the first sprite, so that it can't be seen or interacted with.
I am currently drawing a texture, and then drawing a rectangle in the same place so that i can interact for the rectangle. I could also use the 'sprite' instead.

**Problem:**

I don't know how i can remove the sprite so that it can not be seen and can not be interacted with. I also want to be able to do it the other way, not there then be able to see and interact with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. I am also unsure about what you are asking. Do you want temporarily disable the Sprite? Or do you want to completely remove the sprite?

To temporarily disable the sprite you could do as follows:

```
public class Entity extends Sprite{

    private boolean visible;

    **Constructor and other methods**

    public void setVisible(boolean visible){
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    public boolean isVisible(){
        return visible;
    }

}
```

In your update/render method:

```
Array<Entity> entities = new Array<Entity>();
entities.add(...sprite/entity1, sprite/entity2);

for(Entity entity : entities){

    if(entity.isVisible()){
        entity.update(delta);
        entity.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

if you want to completely remove the Sprite:

```
public class Entity extends Sprite{

    private boolean remove = false;

    **Constructor and other methods**

    public void remove(){
        remove = true;
    }

    public boolean shouldRemove(){
        return remove;
    }         
}
```

In your update/render method:

```
Array<Entity> entities = new Array<Entity>();

for(int i = 0; i < entities.size; i++){
    entities.get(i).update(delta);
    entities.get(i).draw(batch);
    if(entities.get(i).remove()){
        entities.removeIndex(i--);
    }
}
```